# Change content of div based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I've been trying for a long time to make a button appear on a webpage and make the link that button goes to change depending on the radio button selected. However, so far nothing appears on my web page except for the radio buttons. 
This is my code so far:

```html
<div id="quick-book">
    <script>
        if (document.getElementById("radio-restaurant").checked){
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./restaurant.html'>Submit</a>";
        } else if (document.getElementById("radio-hotel").checked){
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./hotel.html'>Submit</a>"
        }
    </script>
    <form name="frmRadio" id="radio-buttons" action="">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-restaurant" name="option" onclick="document.getElementById('radio-buttons').action='';">Restaurant<br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-hotel" name="option" onclick="document.getElementById('radio-buttons').action='';">Hotel<br>
    </form>
    <div name ="button">
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone here can help guide me in the right direction!

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a function in you code and add it when click in the radio.

Something like this:

```html
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById("radio-restaurant").checked){
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./restaurant.html'>Submit</a>";
        } else if (document.getElementById("radio-hotel").checked){
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./hotel.html'>Submit</a>"
        }
    }
    </script>
    
<div id="quick-book">
    <form onchange="myFunction()" name="frmRadio" id="radio-buttons" action="">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-restaurant" name="option" onclick="document.getElementById('radio-buttons').action='';">Restaurant<br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-hotel" name="option" onclick="document.getElementById('radio-buttons').action='';">Hotel<br>
    </form>
    <div id="button">
    </div>
</div>
```

And change name="button" to **id**="button"

Comment: While onclick should work, the prefered event is onchange, because if you click on the edge of the element it will alo fire the event even if the radio button checked state hasn't changed.

Comment: Also you are declaring the onclick 2 times which means the second one will make it to the dom and that isn;t the one you want to add.  So myFunction wouldn't fire

Comment: Yes, you are righ, in this case is better add "onclick" or better "onchange" directly in the form, to don't declaring 2 times. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="quick-book">
  <script>
    function $(e) {
      //Just something I have found useful
      return document.getElementById(e);
    }
    function rb_onchange(s) {
      //First clean up
      $("button").innerHTML = '';
      //The id is added because both radio buttons
      //will fire this event when one changes
      //So to prevent both both conditions firing you have to add this additional condition
      if (s.checked && s.id == "radio-restaurant") {
        //If the radio button is checked and the id of
        //said radio button is the restaurant one then add the innerHTML
        $("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./restaurant.html'>Submit</a>";
      }
      else if (s.checked && s.id == "radio-hotel") {
        //If the radio button is checked and the id of
        //said radio button is the hotel one then add the innerHTML
        $("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./hotel.html'>Submit</a>";
      }
    }
  </script>
  <form name="frmRadio" id="radio-buttons" action="">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-restaurant" name="option" onchange="rb_onchange(this);">Restaurant<br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-hotel" name="option" onchange="rb_onchange(this);">Hotel<br>
  </form>
  <div name ="button"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Seems I failed to notice the id attribute of the button div.,....

Change:

```
<div name ="button"></div>
```

to

```
<div name="button" id="button"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

Adding some comments

Comment: Just nmake sure you have the proper CSS to back it up

Answer (score 0):

First, your `<script>` is executed only once, not on every radio button change. And since initially nothing is checked, script does nothing. Moreover, when this script is executed, elements below are not rendered yet. You need to:

1) Move the script down, below all your divs.

2) Create a `change` callback to check radio buttons values

```html
<div id="quick-book">
    <form name="frmRadio" id="radio-buttons" action="">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-restaurant" name="option" onclick="change(this)">Restaurant<br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-hotel" name="option" onclick="change(this)">Hotel<br>
    </form>
    <div id ="button">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function change(radio) { 
        if (radio.checked && radio.id === "radio-restaurant") {
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./restaurant.html'>Submit</a>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "<a href='./hotel.html'>Submit</a>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div id="quick-book">
        <script>
        function checkRadio(radio) {
           if (radio.id === "radio-restaurant"){
                document.getElementById("button-div").innerHTML = "<a href='./restaurant.html'>Submit</a>";
           } else {
                document.getElementById("button-div").innerHTML = "<a href='./hotel.html'>Submit</a>";
           }
          }
        </script>
        <form name="frmRadio" id="radio-buttons" action="">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-restaurant" name="option" onchange="checkRadio(this)">Restaurant<br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-hotel" name="option" onchange="checkRadio(this)">Hotel<br>
        </form>
        <div id="button-div">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the onchange event will fire  for both radio buttons after one is changed because it is in the same <form> tag.... thus u need to add a condition to check if the radio button is checked as well.

Comment: @JuanTheron please take a look at my code in JSFiddle and look at the Javascript console in your browser, the function checkRadio is called only once when onchange event is triggered. 
https://jsfiddle.net/07jbmk5y/

Comment: I see what you mean.  I guess it might be browser dependant.  I remember I had a situation a couple years back where the event fired twice and I had to resolve the situation as per my answer.  So ever since then I've been doing it my way.  But sure enough your way works, sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
 { 
  $("#watch-me").click(function()
  {
    $("#show-me:hidden").show('slow');
   $("#show-me-two").hide();
   $("#show-me-three").hide();
   });
   $("#watch-me").click(function()
  {
    if($('watch-me').prop('checked')===false)
   {
    $('#show-me').hide();
   }
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  $("#see-me").click(function()
  {
    $("#show-me-two:hidden").show('slow');
   $("#show-me").hide();
   $("#show-me-three").hide();
   });
   $("#see-me").click(function()
  {
    if($('see-me-two').prop('checked')===false)
   {
    $('#show-me-two').hide();
   }
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  $("#look-me").click(function()
  {
    $("#show-me-three:hidden").show('slow');
   $("#show-me").hide();
   $("#show-me-two").hide();
   });
   $("#look-me").click(function()
  {
    if($('see-me-three').prop('checked')===false)
   {
    $('#show-me-three').hide();
   }
  });
  
 });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">

        <form id='form-id'>
            <input id='watch-me' name='test' type='radio' checked /> Radio 1
            <input id='see-me' name='test' type='radio' /> Radio 2
            <input id='look-me' name='test' type='radio' /> Radio 3
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <div id='show-me'>
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Tab Content</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile Tab Content</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages tab Content</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Setting tab Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id='show-me-two' style='display:none; border:2px solid #ccc'>Editing snippet "On Click Change on Radio Button" <br> Editing snippet "On Click Change on Radio Button"</div>
        <div id='show-me-three' style='display:none; border:2px solid #ccc'>Hello I'm Div 3</div>
          
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: sorry for that but this was my first answer on stack.